# Cannot load json file to MAUI Blazor

Tags: blazor, maui

Cannot read JSON file to List  I added the file in directory , and I am trying to read file it is giving me some exception and is not reading file properly.PLease suggest on this.
Please find the link to github here. If not possible I like to read json file inline.

https://github.com/KalyanAllam/MauiAppBurned

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using System.Net.Http.Json
@using System.Text.Json

<PageTitle>Activity Dropdown</PageTitle>

<h3>Activity</h3>

<EditForm Model="@submitActivity" OnSubmit="@Submit">
    <div>
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="submitActivity.CD">
            @if (submitActivity != null)
            {
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                @foreach (var activity in ActivityList)
                {
                    <option value="@activity.CD">@activity.DESC</option>
                }
            }
        </InputSelect>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Weight (in kgs)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input placeholder="Weight (in kgs)" @bind="@weight" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Time  (in minutes)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input placeholder="Time in minutes" @bind="@minutes" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<div>
    <div>@finalresult</div>
</div>

@code {
    private List<ACTIVITY> ActivityList = new();
    private ACTIVITY submitActivity { get; set; } = new();
    private string dataResourceText ;
    private int weight;
    private int minutes;
    private string finalresult = string.Empty;
    private decimal hours;
    private string skip = "";

    string jsonString = @"{

        ""CD"": ""19260"",
         ""METS "": ""2.5"",
        ""CATEGORY"": ""winter activities"",
        ""DESC"": ""snow blower, walking and pushing""
}
";


    ACTIVITY activity = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ACTIVITY>(jsonString);


    private void Submit()
    {
        //Debug - View the CD

        skip = "N";
        if (weight <= 21)
        {
            skip = "Y";
            finalresult = "Invalid Weight";
        }
        if (weight >= 150)
        {
            skip = "Y";

            finalresult = "Invalid Weight";
        }
        if (minutes <= 5)
        {
            skip = "Y";

            finalresult = "Invalid Time";
        }

        if (minutes >= 200)
        {
            skip = "Y";

            finalresult = "Invalid Time";
        }
        //use the CD to get the and display the description
        ACTIVITY model = ActivityList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CD == submitActivity.CD);

        hours = (decimal)minutes / 60;
        if (skip == "N")
        { finalresult = (weight * model.METS * hours).ToString(); }


    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Index index &&
               jsonString == index.jsonString;
    }


    //View Model
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Burned burned { get; set; }
    }

    public class Burned
    {
        public List<ACTIVITY> ACTIVITY { get; set; }
    }

    public class ACTIVITY
    {
        public string CD { get; set; }
        public decimal METS { get; set; }
        public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
        public string DESC { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is “some exception”?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/KalyanAllam/MauiAppBurned I am trying to deseralize json its not working and its giving reload error.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  All relevant details should be included in the body of your post.  If you are getting an error or exception, you should provide the **exact error message**, not a vague description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have cloned your repo and reproduced your problem.

> I am trying to deseralize json its not working and its giving reload error.

It has nothing to do with deseralizing json. **I just removed the `@inject HttpClient Http` and the index.razor can load successfully.**

In addition, you will get a null exception when you click the submit button:

```
        ACTIVITY model = ActivityList.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CD == submitActivity.CD);

        hours = (decimal)minutes / 60;
        if (skip == "N")
        { finalresult = (weight * model.METS * hours).ToString(); }
```

The `model` is null and the `weight * model.METS` will cause **strong text**System.NullReferenceException.

Comment: I fixed the bugs but it is giving deployment error in MAUI https://github.com/KalyanAllam/MauiAppBurned <Doesn't works>                                                                 The same code works in Blazor web app https://github.com/KalyanAllam/BlazorAppHBE

Comment: Can you show th error message? I run the code above well. @KALYANAALLAM

Comment: There were deployment errors .Continue?  , I don't know where to see for depolyment errors

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild the project? @KALYANAALLAM

Answer (score 1):

@Liyun Zhang - MSFT

I am trying to populate ActivityList , I am getting compilation error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' of List ".

https://github.com/KalyanAllam/MauiBlazorHBE

```
  protected override void OnInitialized()
    {

        List<ACTIVITY> ActivityList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ACTIVITY>(jsonString);
        
    }
```

Comment: Did you change the account? You should use the same type. Such as`List<ACTIVITY> ActivityList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ACTIVITY>>(jsonString);`

Comment: In addition, the jsonString should be contained by `[]`, such as `string jsonString = @"[{

        ""CD"": ""19260"",
         ""METS "": ""2.5"",
        ""CATEGORY"": ""winter activities"",
        ""DESC"": ""snow blower, walking and pushing""
}]
"`